# PHP MySQL turn row red if result is above below vertain value

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

Need some help.

I have this query...

```
$query2 = "
SELECT HD_TICKET.ID as ID, 
HD_TICKET.TITLE as Title, 
HD_STATUS.NAME AS Status, 
HD_PRIORITY.NAME AS Priority, 
HD_TICKET.CREATED as Created, 
HD_TICKET.MODIFIED as Modified, 
HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE10 as SLA,
S.FULL_NAME as Submitter, 
O.FULL_NAME as Owner, 
HD_TICKET.RESOLUTION as Resolution,
(SELECT COMMENT FROM HD_TICKET_CHANGE WHERE HD_TICKET_ID=HD_TICKET.ID ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1) as Comment,
HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 as Type 
FROM HD_TICKET 
JOIN HD_STATUS ON (HD_STATUS.ID = HD_TICKET.HD_STATUS_ID) 
JOIN HD_PRIORITY ON (HD_PRIORITY.ID = HD_TICKET.HD_PRIORITY_ID) 
LEFT JOIN USER S ON (S.ID = HD_TICKET.SUBMITTER_ID) 
LEFT JOIN USER O ON (O.ID = HD_TICKET.OWNER_ID)
WHERE (HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID IN( 1,3))
AND (DATE_FORMAT(HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED, '%M') = 'September')
ORDER BY HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED DESC
";
```

And this is the output that shows this in my page.

```
echo "<td>$Title</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Submitter</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Owner</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Status</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Created</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Modified</td> \n";
echo "<td>$SLA</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
```

Is there any way to conditionally turn the row background RED if the modified time is greater than 72 hours for instance?

Basicallty want to flag up any rows that havent been modified in 72 hours.

Thanks.

Comment: stub for php... `if $modified + 72h < now() then background red`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(strtotime($Modified) < strtotime("-72h"))
 echo "<td class='red'>$Modified</td> \n";
else
 echo "<td>$Modified</td> \n";
```